# Eclipse: Getting text between 2 given tags

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I'm trying to get text between 2 given parameters. So get all the text between ( and ) in a certain string. Is there a built in function or will I have to write my own?

For Instance 
`FindBetween(tag1, tag2, StringToSearch)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can be a resolution for your task. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you knew that tag2 always followed tag1 and that they both existed in toSearch, you could use String methods to solve your problem:

```
public String findBetween(String tag1, String tag2, String toSearch)
{
    return toSearch.substring(toSearch.indexOf(tag1) + tag1.length(),
                              toSearch.indexOf(tag2));
}
```

- substring(beg, end) returns the part of toSearch from index beg to
  one character before index end
- finding the index of a String (tag1) within toSearch returns the
  index of the first character of that String so adding the length
  of the String will give you the index of the first character
  following it

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions for this. See [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Here's an example I cooked up:

```
public static List<String> findBetween(String tag1, String tag2, String toSearch) throws IllegalStateException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(
        "%s(.*?)%s",
        // use quote in case tag1/tag2 are special regex characters.
        Pattern.quote(tag1),
        Pattern.quote(tag2)
    ));

    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toSearch);
    while (matcher.find()){
        matches.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    return matches;
}
```

You can see it in operation here: https://ideone.com/NMke7L